# nodejs, What's the difference about NODE_ENV=production and export NODE_ENV=production?

Tags: node.js

in `package.json`:

we can use like this:

```
{
   "build": "NODE_ENV=production && webpack -p"
}
```

But, in `build.sh`:

it must be:

```
export NODE_ENV=production
../../node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
```

if you use

```
NODE_ENV=production
../../node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
```

you will get `undefined` for `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

why?

Comment: You should be able to use `NODE_ENV=production webpack -p` in both.

Answer (score 0):

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```

`export` command is for saving a NODE_ENV to your env, so Node.js will find out all your node env.

but bash script is doesn't recognise the `NODE_ENV=production`

`.sh` files is for bash script. CMIIW